# Is it possible to show a notification to the user after the response from an API is returned and the user has navigated to a different page?

Tags: angular, notifications, frontend, angular2-routing

Firstly, apologies for the lack of code on this, I'm just looking for clarity on if it can be done and what APIs/libraries will allow me to do so.

I have a web app front-end written in Angular. One of the back-end services it fetches data from can often take 2-3 mins to return, due to the location of the server and the nature of the data returned. Right now I have an animated spinner displayed on the front-end until the response is returned, which isn't great, as this prevents the user from doing anything until it receives a response. What I'd like to know, is it possible to send a request from the front-end and allow the user to navigate around the site until a response is returned?

Something like:

Click button > API call sent > user navigates to another page > user navigates another page > API response is returned > notification briefly displayed in the front-end to let the user know their action has complete.

I was looking into push notifications but would prefer the notification to be an actual HTML web element.

Comment: It would be greatly useful if you can provide a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your problem without which i had to just give you an idea of how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is totally doable.

You should have a notification display `component` at the root or the place where you need to display the notifications. Now this component should get the data from a notifications `service` where you can store the response after your said `API` is complete.

All you need to do is to use a Subject/BehaviourSubject in `NotificationService` and push the new value/result to it after API call is finished. Now the notification component will get the new value/response and display the message as needed.

Check this and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53122468/9386929) to see [BehaviourSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784172/9386929) example

Comment: You may not even need to use a subject/behaviorsubject if you make the service a singleton using forRoot. You can just make a public var = null that's updated with whatever you'd like to show in the notification. Listen for when the message != null to show the component