# Get value changes from header component

Tags: angular

I have a account selector (dropdown) in the fixed header component. 
Each time I'm selecting a value in this account selector I want to detect the value change and run function in the current component I'm showing.

What the best practice for it?

Thank's.

Comment: The Best way is to use a Event Emitter and act on the events produced. You can also use another service for sharing the value selected using a BehaviourSubject . See this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423532/9386929

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service